# How can i read this kind of text

Tags: hex

First of all i dont understand all this coding thing, im just doing this out of curiousity and boredom.
So what i want to ask is...

Is there a way to read this in English 
or you know in any languange people speak
(Like any languange, since i can use google translate)

```
\x79\x5D\xEF\xBF\xBD\x0F\xE6\x99\xB8\xEF\xBF\xBD\x5D\x2C\xEF\xBF\xBD\x10\x33\x2D\x23\xEF\xBF\xBD
```

If yes, then how to do it ?
If no, thanks for reading and trying to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people would easily be able to do this with a bit of practice.

As it's a language not designed for humans, it will take a while

The above test is in ASCII.

Broken down: `\xST` is how ASCII is written

`\x` tells the machine to convert to hexadecimal
`ST` are just any one of 0-9 and a-f

So you just have to find the translator tool and start learning

Comment: Not a-z, but A-F